# Node js execute python script one after the other

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, synchronous

i have a React app and i want to use Node to execute a number of scripts ( can be N number of scripts ) when a button is click, one after the other. I also have some state for each script, so when the script is done i want to set his state to "completed".

With some google-ing i ended up with :

```
function runScript(command, args, options, id, callback) {
  const child = childProcess.spawn(command, args, options);

  child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`${data}`);
  });

  child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`${data}`);
  });

  // callback function to change the state to "completed"
  child.on('close', () => callback(id, 'completed'));
}

const deployScripts = () => {
    loadedSteps.forEach((script) => {
      if (script.path.length) {
        const [command, args, options] = getParamBasedOnFile(script.path);
        if (command) {
          //set the script to "active" which means is running
          updateStepStatus(script.id, 'active');
          runScript(command, args, options, script.id, updateStepStatus);
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

It works but of course since its asynchronous is running all the scripts at the same time, which is not what i want.

Then i went and tried to make is synchronous

```
function runScript(command, args, options) {
  const child = childProcess.spawnSync(command, args, options);

  console.log(child.stdout.toString());
  // callback(id, 'completed');  -> doesnt work
  console.log('exit run script function');
}

const deployScripts = () => {
    loadedSteps.forEach((script) => {
      if (script.path.length) {
        const [command, args, options] = getParamBasedOnFile(script.path);
        if (command) {
          updateStepStatus(script.id, 'active');
          runScript(command, args, options, script.id, updateStepStatus);
          updateStepStatus(script.id, 'completed');
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

But the problem with this is that even tho it runs the script 1 by 1, (i can see the output in the console), both script states are set to "complete" at the same time (when i tested it 1 python script has sleep of 5 seconds and another one has a sleep of 10 seconds, so the first one should be set to complete, then after 5 seconds the second one).

Not sure whats the best way is to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can promisify `runScript` and implement series of steps as `async` function, this way you can use `await` to wait for each step to complete before running next step.

```js
const childProcess = require("child_process")

/* mocks */

const loadedSteps = [{path:'foo', id:1}, {path:'bar', id:2}, {path:'baz', id:3}]

function getParamBasedOnFile(path) {
    return ['python', ['-c', "import time;time.sleep(1)"], {}]
}

function updateStepStatus(id, status) {
    console.log(id, status)
}

/* code */

function runScript(command, args, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const child = childProcess.spawn(command, args, options);
        child.on('close', () => resolve(child.stdout.toString()))
    })
}

async function deployScripts() {
    for(const script of loadedSteps) {
        if (script.path.length) {
            const [command, args, options] = getParamBasedOnFile(script.path);
            if (command) {
                updateStepStatus(script.id, 'active');
                await runScript(command, args, options, script.id);
                updateStepStatus(script.id, 'completed');
            }
        }
    }
};

/* main */

deployScripts().then(() => console.log('done'))
```